# Ubuntu 20.04/Firefox 80 does not support E-bay

Tags: firefox, html5

I upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04 only to learn that access to my E-bay searches/ E-bay responses are garbled and useless with Firefox 80 (rendered only as a bulleted list). The ***Chromium*** browser renders the E-bay search responses just fine;  so ***Chromium*** is an **option, but I would like to know what the issue is -- and a FIX**.  I understand that from another posting, that the newest version(s), 76... of Firefox do not support HTML 5. Is that Correct and is the underlying issue? (See: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1286981.)

I find this situation unacceptable for a "stable" version of Ubuntu, and Firefox.
Jerry

Comment: Get ready to eat those "unacceptable" words: 20.04/FF80 renders Ebay properly for me. "*rendered only as a bullet list*" is a classic symptom of a networking problem unrelated to Ubuntu. I have seen that on both FF and Chrome on ISP-throttled connections, and places with slow DNS responses.

Comment: Will have to second user535733 comment.  Have also seen the odd site load as bullet list for a few years.  Would disable all extenstions and see if it happens.

Comment: The lack of html5 would probably not affect a site like ebay, it is more for playing videos.

Comment: Do you have tracking protection on for ebay.com? If you do, open Preferences --> Web Developer --> Network , and reload the page. If you see some content that shows that tracking content is blocked, then that is what is happening. The blocked elements break the page display. In my case, I'm just using Chromium for ebay.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your replies.  The answer from user3169 pointed to the problem.
"Do you have tracking protection on for E-bay.com? If you do, open Preferences
--> Web Developer --> Network , and reload the page. If you see some content
that shows that tracking content is blocked, then that is what is happening.
The blocked elements break the page display. ... "

I did have ***FireFox tracking protection*** **ON**, and NO exceptions entered in the "exceptions list" for E-bay; resetting Tracking options to a "***Standard*"** setting "fixed" the problem I was experiencing; specifically, the E-bay response to a search was being presented (rendered) as a bulleted list.  (So, the first two replies were off the mark with respect to their response.)

I think this is related to an E-bay "***security feature***" that probes a user's machine to see if certain network ports are open and unprotected. Apparently, if you block the probes, E-bay responds differently -- with bulleted lists.

**So, THANK YOU for the pointer**.  As I suggested in my initial query:  The issue was related to FireFox, but I guess that I will have to "eat my words" in that I created the problem by using an option available in FireFox ...; although I am not certain how, because I simply upgraded from U18.04 w/current updates to U20.04 with all the current updates...

THANKS AGAIN  user3169 for a USEFUL pointer vs the first two putdowns.

I hope my reply helps others who experience issues with E-bay and FireFox rendering E-bay searches as a bulleted list.

Jerry